# Updating Recycler View according to Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow :). In the app I'm building the user can see their saved notes in a recycler view as shown (PS: All screenshots are from a real device and not from an emulator and I'm not allowed to embed pictures so here are the links) :
[saved notes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpJQe.jpg)

when they click on a particular note, there is an option to view and edit the note.
But the problem is that after saving the edited note and navigating back to the view notes activity, the notes in the recyclerview are not updated but new items are shown below the original ones :
[updated recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPfCE.jpg)

The same problem happens if I delete an item from the recyclerview i.e the the remaining items are displayed below the original ones, for eg: here i deleted the second note: [second note deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh2O5.jpg)

Also the recyclerview gets updated properly when i navigate back to the mainactivity and again open saved notes activity.
these are the codes:

1. ViewSavedNotesAdapter.java

```
public class ViewSavedNotesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewSavedNotesAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<ViewSavedNotedModel> list;
    Context context;
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    public ViewSavedNotesAdapter() {

    }

    public ViewSavedNotesAdapter(ArrayList<ViewSavedNotedModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.notes_view, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        ViewSavedNotedModel model = list.get(position);
        holder.noteName.setText(model.getNoteName());
        holder.data.setText(model.getData());



        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, SelectedNoteViewActivity.class)
                .putExtra("noteName", model.getNoteName())
                .putExtra("data", model.getData()));
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true)
                        .setTitle("Do you really want to delete this note?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                String name = model.getNoteName();
                                String userId = auth.getUid();
                                DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                        .getReference();
                                Query delete = reference.child("UserData").child(userId)
                                        .orderByChild("Note Name").equalTo(name);
                                delete.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                        for (DataSnapshot deleteSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            deleteSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                                        }
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        })
                        .show();

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateList(ArrayList<ViewSavedNotedModel> newList) {
        this.list = newList;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView noteName, data;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            noteName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_name);
            data = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.data);
        }
    }
}
```

2. SavedNotesActivity.java

```
public class SavedNotesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivitySavedNotesBinding activitySavedNotesBinding;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ArrayList<ViewSavedNotedModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseAuth auth;
    ViewSavedNotesAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        activitySavedNotesBinding = ActivitySavedNotesBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activitySavedNotesBinding.getRoot());
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SavedNotesActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading Saved Notes");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait, your saved notes are being loaded");
        progressDialog.show();

        String userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("UserData").child(userId);

        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                if (snapshot.exists()) {


                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String noteName = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Note Name").getValue();
                        String data = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Data").getValue();


                        list.add(new ViewSavedNotedModel(noteName, data));
                        adapter = new ViewSavedNotesAdapter(list,
                                SavedNotesActivity.this);
                        activitySavedNotesBinding.notesView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        activitySavedNotesBinding.notesView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager
                                (SavedNotesActivity.this));
                        adapter.updateList(list);

                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Snackbar.make(activitySavedNotesBinding.notesView, "There are no notes",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Snackbar.make(activitySavedNotesBinding.notesView, "Failed to load Data",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

I've been trying to figure out the issue but unfortunately couldn't. Any help would be really appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to clear the list of notes before adding the new ones in `onDataChange`:

```
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

         if (snapshot.exists()) {
             list.clear();

             for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                 ...
```

Comment: Well that really helped Man, Thanks a lot. Never thought about clearing the list xD. But there's another issue, the last note on the list is not cleared when deleted, but gets cleared when going back to the mainactivity and then coming back. All notes are instantly cleared on clicking delete except the last one .. What could be the solution..??